Movie with disturbing initiation ritual (sometime 2004-2008)
It's an espionage thriller set in a college and focusing on two students. A most memorable scene is during initiation when, while struggling through one of the tasks, the protagonist sees his friend and/or classmate (the one that introduced him, if I remember correctly) urinating on him from the balcony. He reproaches him for this later when they meet.
One of the professors was a German spy who would get killed later in low-paced dark street scene, betrayed by his student.

It all sounds like The Good Shepherd from 2006 with Matt Damon and Angelina Jolie (among others).

Laconic and self-contained, Edward Wilson heads CIA covert operations during the Bay of Pigs. The agency suspects that Castro was tipped, so Wilson looks for the leak. As he investigates, he recalls, in a series of flashbacks, his father's death, student days at Yale (poetry; Skull and Bones), recruitment into the fledgling OSS, truncated affairs, a shotgun marriage, cutting his teeth on spy craft in London, distance from his son, the emergence of the Cold War, and relationships with agency, British, and Soviet counterparts.

As part of the Skull & Bones ritual, a man stands on a balcony and urinates on the pledges. Edward is also asked to expose his professor as a German spy, and the professor is later killed (beaten to death in the street, I think). Here's the trailer:



